# (Noob question) preparing the model for sculpting

Tags: modeling, sculpting

I have a very simple low-poly mesh, and I want to sculpt on top of it to add fine detail. I would like to automatically subdivide the mesh to prepare it for sculpting, but the faces of the model are uneven in area, so selecting everything and clicking “subdivide” a few times results in a very uneven mesh, with a very high resolution in places where I would prefer it to be way lower, and vice versa.

What are the in-built Blender tools to control the resolution? For example, if it could subdivide automatically with resolution proportional to the area of each face, that would already be fantastic.

Comment: Search for "Remesh" and "Dyntopo".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have basically two options to go from here but keep in mind that both of them (and sculpting in general) are **destructive** meaning they're irreversible. So if you like your low-poly mesh it would be smart to make a fallback-copy of it (`Shift+D`) and put it in a separate collection that you can hide, so it doesn't bother you during sculpting.

With that being said here are your options:

1. You can **Voxel-Remesh** your object (the function can be found in the Sculpting tab on the right hand side) to get evenly detailed geometry that you can work with.
2. You can use **Dyntopo** (short for dynamic topology, can be found just above the remeshing tools) which will dynamically add more, finer topology depending on how far you're zoomed in. It takes some time to get used to but it's really fast and handy once you're comfortable with it.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer